# Scoped Collection Group Queries

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Consider a multi-tenant firestore database:

```
/customers/{customerId}/users/{userId}/rosters/{rosterId}
```

Since it seems `collectionGroup` is scoped to the entire database. So in node:

```
let rosters = db.collectionGroup('rosters').where('isActive', '==', 'true');
```

would return matches for all customers. For client side this can be scoped through security rules.

How can it be scoped in admin access?

Comment: I know I could add a customerId field to each document,but that seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: `For client side this can be scoped through security rules` - have you verified this? I think query fails if the current user doesn't have read access to any of the collections matched by the collection group ID
If this scoping through security rules is working for you, Please provide me sample security rules written for collection group query.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_collection_group_queries_based_on_a_field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Collection group queries are applied to all collections that have the name you specify. There is currently no way to scope them beyond that. Long term the plan is to allow scoping to paths, but there's no timeline for when that might be available, and it definitely won't be in the near future.

This means that you'll either need to be able to reduce the scope through the collection name (e.g. if you'd have multiple types of rosters, you might want to rename the collections under `users` to `user_rosters` so that you can limit a collection-group-query to just user's rosters), or through additional field conditions in your query.

While the latter case might feel like you're going back to global collections, it's actually still better than that, since the subcollections do result in better *write* throughput.

Comment: One solution would be a field on every doc that is an array of its path. then in the CGQ you could add db.collectionGroup('rosters').where('_path', 'array-contains', customerId).where('isActive', '==', 'true');  You guys could even pre-compute it on every doc write as a special 'hidden' field:)